# "type of determiner" vs. "type of determiners"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/a-an-and-the)

> "A/an" and "the" are articles. They are a **type of determiner** and they go before a noun.

"A", "an", and "the" are three determiners, while the tutorial uses the singular form of "determiner", why is that?

One of the possible reasons might be that they are **one type**. In contrast, in this situation I should use the plural form of it, as there are **three types**.

> *Articles, Demonstratives,* and *Possessives* are three types of **determiners**.

Is my understanding right?

Comment: See [Determiners](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners), also at Cambridge Dictionary: "Determiners include the following common types …"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct that articles are a single type of determiner, which is why the sentence you gave uses 'type' and not 'types'. The pronoun `they` in the phrase `They are a type of determiner` is referring to 'articles'. As you say, articles are one type of determiner. Thus, they are 'a type'. If there were more than one type, you might say, `They are two types of determiners`. It might also be worth looking into [countable / uncountable nouns](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/nouns-countable-and-uncountable). If the kinds of thing you were referring to were uncountable, you would say something like "There are two types of people..."